# Networkx graph in Python Getting Error "_CachedPropertyResetterNode"

Tags: python, networkx

`P1_Graphs` is a list containing 5 networkx graphs. Each of these graphs were generated by one of three possible algorithms:

- Preferential Attachment (`'PA'`)
- Small World with low probability of rewiring (`'SW_L'`)
- Small World with high probability of rewiring (`'SW_H'`)

Anaylze each of the 5 graphs using any methodology and determine which of the three algorithms generated each graph.

*The `graph_identification` function should return a list of length 5 where each element in the list is either `'PA'`, `'SW_L'`, or `'SW_H'`.*

````
I've got the error "_CachedPropertyResetterNode". Here is the code :

```Python

import pickle
P1_Graphs = pickle.load(open('assets/A4_graphs','rb'))
P1_Graphs

def histogram(G):
    degrees = G.degree()
    degree_values = sorted(set(dict(degrees))) 

    # Calculate the frequency of each unique degree value
    hist = [list(dict(degrees).values()).count(i) / float(nx.number_of_nodes(G)) for i in degree_values]

    return hist

def graph_identification():
    # Calculate features for each graph in P1_Graphs
    features = []
    for G in P1_Graphs:
        hist_length = len(histogram(G))
        clustering_coefficient = nx.average_clustering(G)
        shortest_path_length = nx.average_shortest_path_length(G)

        features.append((hist_length, clustering_coefficient, shortest_path_length))

    # Classify graphs based on their features
    results = []
    for feature_set in features:
        if feature_set[0] > 10:
            results.append('PA')
        elif feature_set[1] > 0.1:
            results.append('SW_L')
        else:
            results.append('SW_H')

    return results

graph_identification()

```
Do you have any idea to solve my problem ?

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 32
     28             results.append('SW_H')
     30     return results
---> 32 graph_identification()

Cell In[5], line 14, in graph_identification()
     12 features = []
     13 for G in P1_Graphs:
---> 14     hist_length = len(histogram(G))
     15     clustering_coefficient = nx.average_clustering(G)
     16     shortest_path_length = nx.average_shortest_path_length(G)

Cell In[5], line 3, in histogram(G)
      1 def histogram(G):
      2     degrees = G.degree()
----> 3     degree_values = sorted(set(dict(degrees))) 
      5     # Calculate the frequency of each unique degree value
      6     hist = [list(dict(degrees).values()).count(i) / float(nx.number_of_nodes(G)) for i in degree_values]

File ~\networkx\classes\reportviews.py:530, in DegreeView.__iter__(self)
    528 weight = self._weight
    529 if weight is None:
--> 530     for n in self._nodes:
    531         nbrs = self._succ[n]
    532         yield (n, len(nbrs) + (n in nbrs))

TypeError: '_CachedPropertyResetterAdj' object is not iterable
````

Comment: Please add the full error message with stacktrace (even if it is long) as well as an example of `P1_Graphs` that generates the error.